# javax.validator is not recognizing violations?

Tags: java, validation, annotations, constraints

This is my own constraint

```
@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 5, message = "ID should be up to {integer} digits")
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface ValidId {
    String message() default "Invalid ID";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Implemenetation:

```
    @Override
    public void deleteClient(@ValidId Long id) throws ValidationException {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Long>> violations = this.validator.validate(id); 
        ValidationHandler.handleViolations(violations);
    }
```

So i am passing invalid value, like 4565465165, and when the validation is done , i've got cero violations. The fact is that if i validate with javax.validation.constraints.Digits directly without my annotation , it doesn't work neither:

```
@Override
public void deleteClient(@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 5) Long id) throws ValidationException {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Long>> violations = this.validator.validate(id); 
    ValidationHandler.handleViolations(violations);
}
```

Then i have none violations again. Do you know what am i doing wrong?